# How to get past a circular meta refresh with Requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, refresh, meta

I'm trying to web scrape using Requests. My code so far is the usual:

```
    import requests   
    html = requests.get('https://www.sampleurl.com').text
```

This gives:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><HTML lang=en><HEAD><TITLE>Company Name</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=https://www.sampleurl.com"></HEAD><BODY>
```

The url inside CONTENT is the same as the url I put into Requests, so it's not a redirect that I can follow by extracting the url with BeautifulSoup. Is there some way of bypassing circular meta refreshes so I can get to the html of the website?

Comment: Can you share the URL so we can look at it?

Comment: Try using requests.session(), it's probably trying to set a cookie.

Comment: @pguardiario this sorted it! Thanks so much! Hadn't come across session() before, useful one to know